# jQuery check if email address part of string in array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if an email address is equal to or a substring of any string in 3 different arrays. Unfortunately, the function I wrote keeps giving an "Unrecognized expression" error.

```
var search = 'info@example.com'
jQuery.each(array1, array2, array3, jQuery(function(index, value) {
  jQuery.each(value, jQuery(function(key, cell) {
    if (jQuery(search).indexOf(cell) !== -1)
      console.log('Found email in ' + index, cell)
  }))
}))
```

This throws following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: info\\@example\\.com
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `info@example.com` is not a valid DOM element or expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First issue the each needs the three arrays wrapped as a single array. Second issue is the use of `jQuery` before the anonymous functions. Third issue is having the `search` string wrapped in a jQuery object (this is the one that triggers the error).

Updated - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wt1L4nuz/):

```
jQuery.each([array1, array2, array3], (function(index, value) {
    jQuery.each(value, (function(key, cell) {
        if (search.indexOf(cell) !== -1)
            console.log('Found email in '+index, cell)
    }))
}))
```

Comment: If I remove the jQuery wrapper from the string, it I get following error: jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: b.call is not a function

Comment: This is why I added the wrapper. Based on another Question on SO.

Comment: Did you apply all of the fixes or just that? Take a look at the working demo and compare your code against it, probably missing something....

Comment: You were right. Missed another jQuery wrapper. Thanks!